# WCF how to bind multiple service contracts?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-binding

First off I'll apologise as this is probably a duplicate but everything I read seems to be either incomplete or confusing as I'm very new to WCF.

I basically am looking to deploy a WCF service in IIS with 2 endpoints accessible and have been going around in circles all day :(

I have a service library WCF dll with the following structure

```
App.config
TestSvc1.cs
ITestSvc1.cs
TestSvc2.cs
ITestSvc2.cs
```

This works fine in the VS WCF test client and now im deploying to IIS so I created a WCF Service Application and referenced the dll. This project has the following structure

```
Service1.svc
Web.config
```

`Service1.svc` contains this

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
    Service="WCFServices.TestServices.ITestSvc1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" %>
```

and my `web.config` has the following

```
<services>
   <service name="WCFServices.TestServices.TestSvc2">
      <endpoint 
          address="" 
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeSizeMessages" 
          contract="WCFServices.TestServices.ITestSvc2">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint 
           address="mex" 
           binding="mexHttpBinding"  
           contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      <host>
         <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/wcf2/TestServices/TestSvc2/" />
         </baseAddresses>
      </host>
   </service>
   <service name="WCFServices.TestServices.TestSvc1">
      <endpoint 
          address="" 
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeSizeMessages" 
          contract="WCFServices.TestServices.ITestSvc1"  
          listenUri="http://localhost:8080/wcf2/service1.svc">
          <identity>
            <dns value="" />
          </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint 
          address="" 
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeSizeMessages" 
          contract="WCFServices.TestServices.ITestSvc2" 
          listenUri="http://localhost:8080/wcf2/service1.svc">
          <identity>
            <dns value="" />
          </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      <host>
         <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/wcf2/TestServices/TestSvc1/" />
         </baseAddresses>
      </host>
   </service>     
</services>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. As you can see I've tried to add an additional endpoint in the `web.config` but this doesn't work, I get an error saying that TestSvc2 calls can't be found in TestSvc1 which I guess relates to the entry in `Service1.svc`

I also read about creating a class that inherits these interfaces but I am not sure exactly how to implement it based on what I have above. Do I need to modify the `Service1.svc`?

```
public interface MultipleSvc : ITestSvc1, ITestSvc2
{
   // What exactly do I put here? I have no idea, do I leave it blank? This didn't work for me
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated guys thanks :)

Comment: One little thing I see is that you have specified different namespaces for service 1 and 2, namely WCFServices.TestServices.ITestSvc1 and WCFServices.TestService.ITestSvc2.  Note the missing s in TestServices.ITestSvc2.

Comment: Yeah sorry thats just a typo for here just to illustrate things better, ill edit that :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Golden rule: **one `.svc` = one service** (or more specifically: one service *implementation* class)

So if you do have two separate, distinct services (in classes `WCFServices.TestServices.TestSvc1` and `WCFServices.TestServices.TestSvc2`), then you need **two `.svc` files** (one each, for each service)

What you *could* do is have **one service implementation class** that implements both service contracts:

```
public class MultipleServices : ITestSvc1, ITestSvc2
{
   // implement the service logic here, for both contracts
}
```

In that case, **one svc file** will be enough (the `.svc` file is **per implementation class** and can host multiple service contracts). But then you'd need to change your config, too - since you really only have **one service class** (therefore: one `<service>` tag) and multiple contracts hosted inside it:

```
<services>
   <service name="WCFServices.TestServices.MultipleServices">
      <endpoint 
          address="Service1" 
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeSizeMessages" 
          contract="WCFServices.TestServices.ITestSvc1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="" />
          </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint 
          address="Service2" 
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeSizeMessages" 
          contract="WCFServices.TestServices.ITestSvc2">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint 
           address="mex" 
           binding="mexHttpBinding"  
           contract="IMetadataExchange" />
   </service>     
</services>
```

Also: since you seem to be hosting your WCF service in IIS, there's no point in defining any `<baseAddress>` values - the "base" address of your service is the location (URI) where the `*.svc` file lives.

Comment: I'd go with the 2 svc files as suggested here for simplicity.

Comment: thanks guys, tried the singl svc and got it working, it has however for some reason dropped the wshttpbinding when deployed and comes through with basichttp - strange one! i'll test with two svc files and see if the result is the same

Comment: yeah when its two seprate files the binding remains as wshttp any ideas why it drops when theyre combined?

Comment: +1 *Also: since you seem to be hosting your WCF service in IIS, there's no point in defining any <baseAddress> values - the "base" address of your service is the location (URI) where the *.svc file lives.*.

Comment: @marc_s i asked a same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155744/multi-service-contract-in-one-endpoint-c-sharp-wcf with but a little different .could you please take a look ?

Answer (score 0):

You do'nt need two svc file. Choose ServiceReference1.Service1Client or ServiceReference1.Service2Client.